# How to use multiple comparison operators at once

Tags: python, python-3.x

class Fraction:

```
def __init__(self, top, bottom):
    self.top = top
    self.bottom = bottom

def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.top}/{self.bottom}"

def __ne__(self, other):
    ne_first_top = self.top * other.bottom
    ne_second_top = self.bottom * other.top
    return ne_first_top != ne_second_top

def __eq__(self, other):

    first_top = self.top * other.bottom
    second_top = other.top * self.bottom

    return first_top == second_top

f1 = Fraction(2, 3)
f3 = Fraction(1, 4)
assert f1 != f3 == True
```

When I run this code, I get the error AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'bottom'. Can I run this code without changing last line?

Answer (score 1):

The last line is incorrect because `f3 == True` is being evaluated first.  It'd work if you did:

```
assert (f1 != f3) == True
```

or more simply (because `True == True` is always `True`):

```
assert f1 != f3
```

*Technically* you could make it "work" by forcing `f3 == True` to return `f3`, so that `f1 != (f3 == True)` will actually do what you want it to do:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other == True:
            return self
```

but don't do that.  It would be extremely silly.

Note that since you've defined `__eq__`, you don't need to explicitly define `__ne__` as its opposite.  If `__ne__` isn't explicitly defined it will just automatically be interpreted as "`not __eq__`"; Python doesn't generally force you to do extra work if it can at all be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare objects of different classes, you could amend your **eq**() method to handle it gracefully. At its simplest, you can do:

```
def __eq__(self, other):

    if type(self) == type(other):
        first_top = self.top * other.bottom
        second_top = other.top * self.bottom
        return first_top == second_top
    else:
        return False
```

Of course, if you want `Fraction(1,1) == True` to return `True`, then you'll need to elaborate your `__eq__()` method a bit further.